# Is there any algorithm to find just the largest eigenvalue with subquadratic time complexity?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

SVD or PCA can be used find the largest eigenvalue, but at a cost of $O(n^3)$ complexity. Lanczos algorithm runs much faster on a sparse matrix with complexity $O(dn^2)$ where $d$ is the average number of non-zeros in a row. It is better, but still quadratic.

My question is does anyone know any sub quadratic algorithm to find just the largest eigenvalue. It can be a very approximate algorithm that just capture the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Very fast *estimation* can be obtained from [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that is impossible even in theory: it takes quadratic time to simply *read* a matrix. If an algorithm fails to inspect even a single entry, it can't possibly know (outside of rare exceptions) the largest eigenvalue, because that single entry could be so large in magnitude as to render the rest of the matrix basically irrelevant.

You would have to restrict to special matrix forms to have any hope of achieving subquadratic time.